# xcode 7.1 subverison repository fails authentication

Tags: xcode, authentication, svn

I attempted to add a subversion repository to my XCode accounts in XCode preferences and got a response of "authentication failed". I know my credentials are good and can login from chrome and other SVN client apps but none will let me commit. I Have never used a repository with XCode before and Have no experience with subversion either. Could this be an issue with the SVN setup or is XCode the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced same & found:

The repository get cloned on other system using Xcode 7.0 but with Xcode 7.1 on another system facing the issue. So the cause of issue is not Svn but Xcode 7.1

**Workaround**: Clone code copy using Xcode 7.0 or Xcode 6 & then use Xcode 7.1 for development & try whether update work or not.

Other: with Xcode 7.1 also facing some weird deployment issue [Adhoc & Appstore app submission]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339341/provisioning-profile-has-udid-but-the-ipa-doesnt-have-it-resulting-in-app-not-g

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried with Xcode 6 and 7.0 but I'll try again.