# Provisioning profile has UDID but the ipa doesnt have it, resulting in app not getting installed

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa, ios-provisioning, udid

Am Facing a weird situation where in, i have a provisioning profile with a UDID added in it, i tried opening profile through textEdit and i can see the UDID when i generate a build and upload it to https://betafamily.com/supersend i didnt see that UDID in the list provided,and am unable to install the build on that device.

I tried generating another provisioning profile and generated a new ipa but no luck,
Has any one faced this issues earlier?

Comment: What XCode version do you use?

Comment: You can also use http://www.diawi.com to upload app. With this link also you can upload in device.

Comment: I Tried with Xcode version 7.0

Comment: @Syed i am facing same, today

Comment: Unxip the .ipa and open the embedded.mobileprovision file.  See if it has the UDID in it.  Otherwise, you are building with the wrong provisioning profile / signing identity.

Answer (score 1):

Till Xcode 7.0 GM it was working as expected.

The problem started from Xcode 7.1.

**The Issue:** In project configuration file you select new provisional certificated but in archive file it points to old [So the archive file display the UDID of old provisional certificates & not the UDID [Added UDID] of new provisional certificate].

**The Solution:** [Temporary Solution] Delete all provision certificate from iPhone Configuration certificate & Xcode Provisioning Profiles folder [Image Below]. Just download [No need to recreate or other stuff] the new adhoc provisional certificate & install.
Close Xcode, Restart & create archive. This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, I tried generating ipa through Xcode 6, and it worked fine.may be some issue with Xcode 7.0 and above

Comment: Yes its exactly at 7.1 & not at 7.0. I am sure because at 7.0 everything was working fine but as soon as i updated to 7.1. The given issues emerged along with other App Store deployment issues. Thanks for your question which helped me to pick that i am on correct path.